# How to pass a list to a function then sort and count the occurrence of items respectively using Python?

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

With a list like this:  `["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]`

I tried to pass the list to a function and sort it as follows:

```
def l(fruits):
  for i in fruits:
    print(i)

n = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]

l(sorted(n))
```

I only got the result like this:

```
Apple
Apple
Banana
Banana
Orange
Peach
```

I am wondering how to count the occurrence of each item in the list respectively to get the output like this:

```
Apple 2
Banana 2
Orange 1
Peach 1
```

I know using `collections.Counter` can get a similar result, however, I would like the output to be the same as above.

Edit:
I just found out the items in the list should be in lower case.

Also, I tried doing it without `collections_counter`

```
def fruit_list(fruits):
  for i in fruits:
    fruit_occurence = fruits.count("apple")
    fruit_occurence2 = fruits.count("banana")
    fruit_occurence3 = fruits.count("peach")
    fruit_occurence4 = fruits.count("orange")
    if i == "apple":
      print(i.title(), *{fruit_occurence})
    elif i == "banana":
      print(i.title(), *{fruit_occurence2})
    elif i == "peach":
      print(i.title(), *{fruit_occurence3})
    elif i == "orange":
      print(i.title(), *{fruit_occurence4})


f = ["apple", "banana", "peach", "apple", "banana", "orange"]

fruit_list(sorted(f))
```

Output:

```
Apple 2
Apple 2
Banana 2
Banana 2
Orange 1
Peach 1
```

Is there anyway to remove the duplicate items in the output? Changing the list to set would affect the fruit_occurances.

Comment: Do you want that sorted by count or by fruit name?

Comment: the fruit name.

Comment: Though, I am curious to know if it is possible to do it with built-in functions only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` then use `sorted` in `for` in `function` then use `print(*...)` like below:

```
from collections import Counter

def l(fruits):
    for i in sorted(Counter(fruits).items()):
        print(*i)

n = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]

l(n)
```

Output:

```
Apple 2
Banana 2
Orange 1
Peach 1
```

Comment: Thank you! It it works like a charm.

Comment: @PypypieYum welcome :)

Comment: I just edited the question, I found out that the items should all be lower case, is there anyway to make the first letter be upper case?

Comment: @PypypieYum chang this line : `for i in fruits:` to this`for i in set(fruits):`

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that sorted() should be added to the for statement instead of the last part

Answer (score 1):

Use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter


def l(fruits):
    c = Counter(fruits)
    for fruit, count in sorted(c.items()):
        print(fruit, count)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Comment: I just edited the question, I found out that the items should all be lower case, is there anyway to make the first letter be upper case?

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying `l` at all,

```
>>> l(f'{f} {c}' for f, c in sorted(Counter(n).items()))
```

The trick is to create a generator expression that produces the strings you want to print from the `Counter` instance.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should be work for you

```
import collections

fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
d = {}
for fruit in fruits:
  if fruit in d:
    d[fruit] += 1
  else:
    d[fruit] = 1

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
print (od)
```

Comment: I think else is missing a colon, also, when i execute it, it gives me " KeyError: 'Apple' "

Comment: @PypypieYum could you check one more time?

Comment: Thanks, it works now

Comment: Thank you as well